# Grails Controller var from session scope (Grails 3)

Tags: session, grails, scope, controller

I now use the newly Grails version 3.0.4, when I set a controller variable with a session value my application does not run.

My controller class:

```
class AppSecController {

   def sessionObject = SessionVars.mySessionObject()


}
```

I was used this way to get session values on controller vars in older grails versions, and this run successfully, but in Grails 3.0.4 it doesn't works.

The sessioned vars are defined on before() method from an initial Interceptor.

The error stack:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.company.core.security.AppSecController': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.company.core.security.AppSecController]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1101)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:52)
at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:322)
at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:311)
at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at core.Application.main(Application.groovy:27)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.company.core.security.AppSecController]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
    at org.grails.spring.beans.factory.OptimizedAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.instantiate(OptimizedAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:89)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder$currentRequestAttributes.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
    at com.company.core.SessionHandler.getSession(SessionHandler.groovy:19)
    at com.company.core.SessionHandler.getVar(SessionHandler.groovy:31)
    at com.company.core.SessionHandler$getVar$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at com.company.core.security.SessionVars.mySessionObject(SessionVars.groovy:40)
    at com.company.core.security.SessionVars$mySessionObject.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
    at com.company.core.security.AppSecController.<init>(AppSecController.groovy:10)
    at com.company.core.security.AppSecController.<init>(AppSecController.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
```

Please if anyone has been able to directly session objects on controller vars. Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't do that: store a session related variable as a property in a controller. Controllers are multithreaded clasess (servlets really). The container will create a pool of controllers and then it will reuse them for different requests. If you store a session variable in a controller the results are impredecible. Why don't you just access the session variable in the controller methods where you need it?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I want to use a controller with this properties because I need to reuse to much any variables (user, location, etc), then I wont create a way to access directly for these variables. As I says it is posible on grails old versions and we was use to long time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controllers are be default `singleton` this means only one exists for the whole application and is created at startup time, hence you cannot access session variables.

One option is to change the scope to `prototype`, this will create a new controller for  each request. In your controller class define:

```
 static scope = 'prototype'
```

Comment: Thank you,  with these 'scope' the traits and controllers are running as we want!